# ResultSet outputted String is refusing to Cast to a Dict with DynamoDB noSQL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, resultset

I am trying to cast a ResultSet to a Dict, however the Python casts do not appear to want to work correctly.

#### Connection to AWS DynamoDB

```
c   = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(aws_access_key_id="ACCESSKEYCODE222",aws_secret_access_key="SECRETKEYCODEKFJFJFJF",region_name="us-west-2")
table  = Table("reko_response",connection=c)

# Get the result set from DynamoDB
response = table.scan()
print(type(response)) # type of the response recieved = <class 'boto.dynamodb2.results.ResultSet'>
```

#### Test the standard string to dict conversion which works correctly

```
string_of_dict = "{'name':'Frederik'}"
dict_of_string = ast.literal_eval(string_of_dict)
print(type(dict_of_string)) # Outputs Correction: <class 'dict'>
```

This works correctly and the string is cast to a dict.

#### The ResultSet Casts to a String which Refuses to Cast to a Dict

```
for item in response:
    string_item = json.dumps(str(dict(item)))
    print(string_item)

    print(type(string_item)) # Outputs correctly: <class 'str'>

    # Cast to Dict Attempt 1
    dict_item = json.loads(string_item)
    print(type(dict_item)) # Expected Output: <class 'dict'> | Actual Output: <class 'str'> 

    # Cast to Dict Attempt 2
    dict_item = ast.literal_eval(string_item)
    print(type(dict_item)) # Expected Output: <class 'dict'> | Actual Output: <class 'str'> 

    sys.exit()
```

Neither of the standard Python casts appear to caste the string of the result set to a dict.

What is happening here?

The Actual output is

```
<class 'boto.dynamodb2.results.ResultSet'>
<class 'dict'>
"{'timestamp': 'Time: 2018-05-02 08:42:36.978210', 'ID': '39609c57-6ed5-4fc5-8baa-0007d1aeb7ef', 'Store': 'Coles:Brighton', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age(high)': Decimal('43'), 'smile': False, 'smile_conf': Decimal('90.57567596435546875'), 'Emotion1': 'HAPPY', 'emo2-conf': Decimal('6.381499767303466796875'), 'Emotion3': 'CALM', 'emo1-conf': Decimal('19.021503448486328125'), 'Age(low)': Decimal('26'), 'emo3-conf': Decimal('5.70695400238037109375'), 'Emotion2': 'SAD'}"
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

#### The expected and target output is

```
<class 'boto.dynamodb2.results.ResultSet'>
<class 'dict'>
"{'timestamp': 'Time: 2018-05-02 08:42:36.978210', 'ID': '39609c57-6ed5-4fc5-8baa-0007d1aeb7ef', 'Store': 'Coles:Brighton', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age(high)': Decimal('43'), 'smile': False, 'smile_conf': Decimal('90.57567596435546875'), 'Emotion1': 'HAPPY', 'emo2-conf': Decimal('6.381499767303466796875'), 'Emotion3': 'CALM', 'emo1-conf': Decimal('19.021503448486328125'), 'Age(low)': Decimal('26'), 'emo3-conf': Decimal('5.70695400238037109375'), 'Emotion2': 'SAD'}"
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
```

Meaning the last two prints, are printing out strings which *should* have been cast to a dict but remain as strings.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that I could not cast the result set into a Dict, however I could assign the values of the ResultSet to a new Dict by the reference to the value of each of the items I intend to include in the new Dict.

For example, say the goal is to separate the items by gender the loop for the solution would be:

#### Separate males from females in loop:

```
for item in response:
    female_smile = {}
    male_smile = {}

    print("start")

    # Get Dicts of Females who are smiling over time
    if item['Gender'] == 'Female':
        female_smile['timestamp'] = item['timestamp']
        female_smile['Store'] = item['Store']
        female_smile['smile'] = item['smile']
        female_smile_list.append(female_smile)
    # Get Dicts of Males who are smiling over time  
    else: 
        male_smile['timestamp'] = item['timestamp']
        male_smile['Store'] = item['Store']
        male_smile['smile'] = item['smile']
        male_smile_list.append(male_smile)
```

The question is not entirely answered, being "how do I cast a ResultSet to a Dict". That said the desired outcome was to form a new Dict from the ResultSet which was achieved by assigning the values of the ResultSet to a Dict.